# Intersymbol Interference

Tags: matlab

Currently I have generated a ISDN 2B1Q signal and added a random signal to it,then I have designed a lowpass butterworth filter to remove the noise as much possible in MATLAB.
[image]

My next task is to add Intersymbol Interference to this 2B1Q signal and implement DFE using LMS algortihm to reduce this ISI.Can anybody help me as to how I can add ISI to this signal in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate an ISI (inter symbol interference) effect, by passing the message signal pulses through a **dispersive** communication channel model filter.

The dispersive channel will spread the pulses and make them overlap, hence creating ISI.

You can simulate a dispersive channel via nonlinear phase filtering or multi path effects.

Comment: Can I use the Rayleigh Channel for this purpose?Can Rayleigh channel produce the ISI?

Comment: What is your specific Rayleight channel model ?

Comment: I just need to add ISI to my signal.I am thinking of using Rayleigh SISO block for simplicity,but i dont know what should be the parameter values of the channel to achieve the ISI.

Comment: ok. Then aply Rayleigh channel and observe ISI pattern... I hope you know how to determine if there is ISI or not on the given channel output.

Comment: Yes I can tell when there is ISI,but the problem is that i cannot configure the MIMO block to achieve the ISI pattern.What should be the parameter values like discrete path delays,average path gain etc

Comment: just set and go :-) find by trial and error ;-)

Comment: Sir can you tell me how should be the ISI pattern if I give input as Sine wave?